# jQuery - get value from array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key-value

I have an array of object that looks like this:

```
var result = [{"id":"1", "price":"20.46"}, {"id":"2", "price":"40.00"}]
```

Right now I can access it like this:

```
result[0].price
```

But what I am trying to do is loop through the array of objects and compare the `id` to a user inputted `id` and return the matching value. So the index should be irrelevant.

I tried to loop through the array of objects, but I probably made some mistake and got nothing back.

```
var userinputid = 1;

result.forEach(function() {
    if (userinputid == result.id) {
        alert(result.price);
    }
);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `result.id` you should use `currentElementInLoop.id`

```js
var result = [{"id":"1","price":"20.46"},{"id":"2","price":"40.00"}]
var userinputid = 1;

result.forEach(function(e) {
  if (userinputid == e.id) alert(e.price);
});
```

Comment: you are right, this solved it. will accept when time runs out

Comment: yeah - that's better solution than my.

Comment: @codenoob If your id's are unique its better to use find `result.find((e) => e.id == userinputid).price;` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1139/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a end brace. And you need to have the function use the element value parameter or the index parameter.
Try

```
result.forEach(function (elementVal) {
    if (userinputid === elementVal.id){
        alert(elementVal.price);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about index:

```js
var result = [{"id":"1","price":"20.46"},{"id":"2","price":"40.00"}]
var userinputid = 1;

result.forEach(function(e, index){
  if(userinputid == result[index].id){
    alert(result[index].price);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the element value parameter or the index parameter

```
result.forEach(function (elementVal) {
    if (userinputid === elementVal.id){
        alert(elementVal.price);
    }
});
```